# C++03 alternative for std::aligned_storage

Tags: c++, c++03

Since C++11 there is a dedicated template struct `std::aligned_storage` and `alignas` keyword for storing aligned data of any chosen type. I am wondering if it is possible to create portable replacement for `std::aligned_storage` that is supported in C++03. The only way I imagine this is creating properly aligned (`unsigned`) `char` array, but how to align it in a right way is a great unknown for me

Comment: Like, https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/aligned_storage.html

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I can read the code, but I'd love to understand why does it work the way it does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to implement `alignof` in C++03 for most types, for example there is a long explanation on [this page](http://www.wambold.com/Martin/writings/alignof.html).

With that, you could use a storage type with that alignment using some template specializations:

```
#include<iostream>

struct alignment {};

template<>
struct alignment<1> {
  typedef char type;
  static const unsigned div_v=sizeof(type);
  static const unsigned add_v=div_v-1;
};
template<>
struct alignment<2> {
  typedef short type;
  static const unsigned div_v=sizeof(type);
  static const unsigned add_v=div_v-1;
};
template<>
struct alignment<4> {
  typedef int type;
  static const unsigned div_v=sizeof(type);
  static const unsigned add_v=div_v-1;
};
template<>
struct alignment<8> {
  typedef double type;
  static const unsigned div_v=sizeof(type);
  static const unsigned add_v=div_v-1;
};

template<typename T>
struct align_store {
  typedef alignment<__alignof(T)> ah;

  typename ah::type data[(ah::add_v + sizeof(T))/ah::div_v];
};

int main() {
  std::cout << __alignof(align_store<int>) << std::endl;
  std::cout << __alignof(align_store<double>) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `Alignof` may be quite useful, but how does it get me closer to `alignas` or `aligned_storage`

Comment: Edited my answer - if you know the alignment of the type, you could use a storage type with the same alignment.

Comment: It helps me a bit, but I would be thankful if You could give an example of how implement aligned storage having this `alignof` operator

Comment: Also added a simple example - I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it works and its short & simple. Note that my example uses the __alignof extension for simplicity, but it should work with the solution in the link too.

Comment: I don't like relying on implementation specific type sizes (`short` is rarely two bytes long) but I get the point

Comment: You could add static assertions about that, and maybe add ifdefs based on a compilers. I don't remember anything generic for this in standard C++03 :( (most compilers of course had uint*_t back then too, so you could use those)

Comment: Without `alignas` you'll still need a way to get the actual pointer to the memory where your object should live inside your aligned_store.

Comment: @rubenvb I fail to see the issue here, what's the problem with the address of data?

Comment: @Dutow it is not aligned properly. `data` is large enough to contain the alignment padding followed by an aligned object. But `&data` will generally not point to a properly aligned memory block in and of itself. Same goes for `std::aligned_storage`.